# How to find maximum value from a Integer using stream in Java 8?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list of `Integer` `list` and from the `list.stream()` I want the maximum value.

What is the simplest way? Do I need comparator?

Comment: Read the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--

Comment: You may have your reasons to use a Stream, but don't forget `Collections.max`..

Answer (score 263, accepted):

You may either convert the stream to `IntStream`:

```
OptionalInt max = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).max();
```

Or specify the natural order comparator:

```
Optional<Integer> max = list.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Or use reduce operation:

```
Optional<Integer> max = list.stream().reduce(Integer::max);
```

Or use collector:

```
Optional<Integer> max = list.stream().collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Or use IntSummaryStatistics:

```
int max = list.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue)).getMax();
```

Comment: Would be interesting to know which one is more efficient.

Comment: May I ask why, Tagir?

Comment: @elect, it first unboxes all the integers, then compares the unboxed ones. 2nd, 3rd and 4th solutions do the unboxing on each comparison effectively doing twice as much unboxing operations. The last one computes more statistics (like sum and min) which is unnecessary here, but will surely take some time.

Comment: If you want to just get an `int`, then `mapToInt(...).max().getAsInt()` or  `reduce(...).get()` to the method chains

Comment: Hi. What about having nulls in the input list? If you put List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(null, 9, 11, 7, 5, null); then each of proposed options fails

Comment: @Bogdan, this is solveable, though apparently was not required in question. Nevertheless you can post your own answer covering this situation.

Comment: Java lambda streams are so bad designed and not intuitive. They should at least overload `list.stream().max()` using the default natural order comparator. Honestly all above options are shit to write, read and remember from a developer point of view. Thats why i come back to the same lambda questions all the time in java my daily language. Just compare same things with c# which i not even work a day per month in and dont even need to lookup things so easy is their lambda. Java messed up big again similar to Date API and now we are stuck.

Comment: How do you know all these methods?

Comment: @Bogdan it's as simple as adding a filter to the stream: `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Answer (score 13):

```
int max = list.stream().reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, (a, b) -> Integer.max(a, b));
```

Comment: This works only, if all of your values are positive. Use Integer.MIN_VALUE instead of 0 in reduce().

Comment: Could also be int max = list.stream()reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer::max);

Answer (score 4):

Another version could be:

```
int maxUsingCollectorsReduce = list.stream().collect(Collectors.reducing(Integer::max)).get();
```

Answer (score 4):

Correct code:

```
int max = list.stream().reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, (a, b) -> Integer.max(a, b));
```

or

```
int max = list.stream().reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer::max);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use below code snipped:

```
int max = list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf)).get();
```

Another alternative:

```
list.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder()); // max value will come first
int max = list.get(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int value = list.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();
System.out.println("value  :"+value );
```

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted many years ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score 3):

I think another easy way is

```
IntSummaryStatistics statistics = List.of(1, 2, 3).stream()
             .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
             .summaryStatistics();
int max = statistics.getMax();
```

With this you can also `getMin()` amd other stuff like mean. A SummaryStatistics Object can be created from other Streams by supplying appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

With stream and reduce

```
Optional<Integer> max = list.stream().reduce(Math::max);
```

Comment: It seems you posted this answer twice and removed the other one, but as I commented on the other one, this solution is already included in Tagir's answer (with `Integer::max` but that's exactly the same).

Answer (score 0):

you can also find the max element in a collection using bellow code:

```java
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
Optional<Integer> max = intList.stream().max((a, b) -> a - b);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, need to convert a String (SeqNum) to integer and find a max value of it.

```
   list.stream().map(TxnCharges::getSeqNum)
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.trim())))
                .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use int max= Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).reduce(0,(a,b)->Math.max(a,b));
works for both positive and negative numbers

Comment: You should start from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to make it work with negative numbers.