# how to find the max value of nested arraylist of string using streams

Tags: arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have an `ArrayList` in the below format

```
List<List<String>> ll = [["0", "a"], ["1", "b"], ["0", "c"], ["1", "d"]]
```

I want to find the maximum value by considering the first position in the nested list. How can I do it using streams?

Using streams how to find the maximum value by taking the position at 
`Integer.parseInt(ll.get(i).get(0))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find maximum value from a Integer using stream in java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378324/how-to-find-maximum-value-from-a-integer-using-stream-in-java-8)

Comment: First questions to narrow this down a bit: Your example seems to have two winners. Which one do we take? Both? First? Last. Do you care about the 2nd value in the nested list?

Comment: If I understand the problem, then it's `ll.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(l -> Integer.parseInt(l.get(0))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the code you posted doesn't even compile. One approach of fetching the largest number from a nested list.

```
List<List<String>> ll = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("10", "a"), Arrays.asList("21", "b"), Arrays.asList("10", "c"),
                Arrays.asList("11", "d"));

OptionalInt max = ll.stream().flatMap(l -> l.stream()).filter(str -> Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)))
                .distinct().mapToInt(i -> Integer.parseInt(i)).max();

System.out.println(max.getAsInt());
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like so,

```
int max = ll.stream().mapToInt(l -> Integer.parseInt(l.get(0))).max()
        .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```