# Where is my list of Integers getting turned into a list of Optional<Integer>?

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm trying to return the max and minimum value of numbers delimited by spaces in a string. Here's what I have so far:

```
public static String HighAndLow(String numbers) {
    List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(numbers.split(" ")).stream()
                                                          .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
                                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    int max = nums.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a > b ? a : b);
    int min = nums.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a < b ? a : b);
    return max + " " + min;
    }
```

But that code won't compile, instead returning"

```
error: incompatible types: Optional<Integer> cannot be converted to int
```

I don't understand... What in my code is converting the integers/strings to Optional? Does map do this by default, or is it unique to the way I'm coding it? I tried doing another map to call the get method on the Optional, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Please **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of the [`Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` returns an `Optional` so that in case you are not getting any value you can specify any default value. So to get `int` in your case you need to define `.orElse()` value like:

```
public static String highAndLow(String numbers) {
        List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(numbers.split(" ")).stream()
                .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        int max = nums.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a > b ? a : b).orElse(0);
        int min = nums.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a < b ? a : b).orElse(0);
        return max + " " + min;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. I couldn't really figure out what the orElse(0) was or where I was supposed to be putting it. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `reduce` operation twice for getting min and max. Just use `IntSummaryStatistics` on `List<Integer>` and get `Max` and  `Min` from this stats and get rid of handling `Optional`

```
public static String HighAndLow(String numbers) {
    IntSummaryStatistics stats = Arrays.stream(numbers.split(" "))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .summaryStatistics();
    return stats.getMax() + " " + stats.getMin();
  }
```

`IntSummaryStatistics` gives you more results other than `max` and `min`

`IntSummaryStatistics{count=10, sum=129, min=2, average=12.900000, max=29}`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an `Optional<Integer>` because that is the return type of [`reduce(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). It returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) because there is no reduced value from an **empty** list.

Of course, in your case, an empty list cannot happen, because if `numbers` is empty, [`numbers.split(" ")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) will return an array of one empty string, and [`Integer.parseInt(s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) will throw `NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`.

Add a [`filter(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) to ignore that empty value. You need to decide what you want your method to return if input is empty, e.g. an empty string.

Now that you know the list isn't empty, you can simply unwrap the `Optional` by calling [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--).

Instead of calling `reduce(...)`, you should use [`max(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) and [`min(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-):

```
public static String highAndLow(String numbers) {
    List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(numbers.split(" ")).stream()
            .filter(s -> ! s.isEmpty())
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (nums.isEmpty())
        return "";
    int max = nums.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
    int min = nums.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
    return max + " " + min;
}
```

Even better, don't box all the numbers into `Integer` objects. Instead of a `Stream<Integer>` you should use an `IntStream`:

```
public static String highAndLow(String numbers) {
    int[] nums = Arrays.asList(numbers.split(" ")).stream()
            .filter(s -> ! s.isEmpty())
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .toArray();
    if (nums.length == 0)
        return "";
    int max = IntStream.of(nums).max().getAsInt();
    int min = Arrays.stream(nums).min().getAsInt(); // Arrays.stream is alternate to IntStream.of
    return max + " " + min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when it performs a reduction operation on the elements of the stream it returns an Optional describing the reduced value. So **reduce operation will wrap to the Optional**. 
Here is the **sample of reduce operation internal implementation**

```java
public final Optional<P_OUT> reduce(){
   boolean foundAny = false;
   T result = null;
   for (T element : this stream) {
      if (!foundAny) {
        foundAny = true;
        result = element;
     }else
       result = accumulator.apply(result, element);
   }
 return foundAny ? Optional.of(result) : Optional.empty();
}
```

In your case you can directly use reduce operation

```java
int max1 = nums.stream().reduce(Integer::max).get();
int min1 = nums.stream().reduce(Integer::min).get();
```

If you want other ways to get min and max values you can see answer of @Tagir Valeev on [how to find maximum value from a Integer using stream in java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378324/how-to-find-maximum-value-from-a-integer-using-stream-in-java-8) question

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String HighAndLow(String numbers) {
    List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(numbers.split(" ")).stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    int max = nums.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a > b ? a : b).orElse(0);
    int min = nums.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a < b ? a : b).orElse(0);
    return max + " " + min;
}
```

The reduce() method with one parameter returns an Optional, which is a Java class for null safety, you can use orElse and define any value which you want for max and min like 0 and 0,

Hope it helps